# Pointer to Structure Given Integer Value

Tags: c, sdl

I'm looking at code from a project that contains a pointer to a structure from the SDL library:

Struct SDL_Window *screen = 1;

I take this to mean that screen is a pointer to the SDL structure. How can a pointer be assigned an integer value? Is this a mistake in the code?

Comment: Looks very suspicious to me ! Also `Struct` is probably in small caps unless its some obfuscated C.

Comment: Yes, it is written "struct". I mistyped, sorry.

Comment: It is a temp value or an error code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many architecture, pointer and integer are stored using the same number of bits. So assigning an integer to a pointer is legal in C. Whereas it is good practice is a very different question ! On gcc 4.8 you get warning:

```
bla.c:2:18: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  struct toto *t = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the compiler warning I have seen as well. I wish I could upvote, but I am 9 reputations short. :(

Comment: Still need four more :( It tells me I need 15.

Comment: The number of bits involved is irrelevant. Integer-to-pointer conversions are permitted because C 2011 6.3.2.3 5 says “An integer may be converted to any pointer type…”. The compiler must implement such conversions even if the number of bits used to represent the integer (whichever type of integer it is) is different from the number of bits used to represent the pointer. However, “the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.”

Comment: Thanks for your comment and answer Eric. Could you give me some reputations so I can upvote you guys?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes people overload pointers to mean other things, such as error or status codes.

It may be bad practice, especially if it is not documented where it is used. The behavior is implementation-dependent, so it should only be used if there is assurance that the C implementation handles the converted values as desired.